# Link word form to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am an IT personnel in a coaching institute. I designed a form on word long ago through which we'd enter the details of the ones coming to get admission. Afterwards, when the number of students in a batch well crossed the limit where we can easily keep track of them, i designed an excel database. Now the only problem left is to devise a way through which i can copy the contents of the form field and link that to the database.
Hope i get something, an easier VBA thing would be fine as well

Comment: This is not a forum for posting job offers

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with vba with this kind of code (use it from your Excel db to load Word docs):

```
Sub DataFrom()

'Remember: this code requires a reference to the Word object model

Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim fName As String
Dim i As Long, Rw As Long

ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Filters.Add "Word", "*.doc", 1
  .Show
  On Error GoTo Exits
  fName = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(fName)

Rw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(Rw, 1) = Cells(Rw - 1, 1) + 1
i = 1
For Each f In wdDoc.FormFields
  i = i + 1
  On Error Resume Next
  Cells(Rw, i) = f.Result
Next
Exits:
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, vba again:O Its a little testing for me. Could you please tell me step by step procedure? I'd be too too thankful. My word files are in a folder on desktop and i need to link ONLY one form field from the word document, which is "Class Test Scores"

And THANKS again!! :)